# Implement IIR SOS structure into FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, matlab, iir

I try to implement an IIR into my FPGA project. I've got the coefficients from my matlab program and implement the gain directly into the coefficients, though I don't need an additional gain multiplier. First I generate the product of the A1,A2,B1 and B2 coefficients, then sum them up, summarize the Input signal with the summation of A1 and A2, then multiply it with b0 and finally create the sum of the B0 product and the B1B2 summation. But my filter doesn't behave like it should in the simulation, is this approach faulty by design or is there some error I don't see in the code?

[image: Signal names and DF-Type]

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;    
use ieee.NUMERIC_STD.ALL; 
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;


entity IIR is
generic (
    OUTPUT_WIDTH : integer := 32;
    INPUT_WIDTH : integer := 32;
    B0 : integer := 14419;         -- = ((2^31)/1,995) * 0,000013396 
    B1 : integer := -14105;          -- = ((2^31)/1,995) * -0,000013103
    B2 : integer := 14419;         -- = ((2^31)/1,995) * 0,000013396 
    A1 : integer := -2147268361;        -- = ((2^31)/1,995) * -1,9948 
    A2 : integer := 1070803162          -- = ((2^31)/1,995) * 0,99477 
    );

port (
    iCLK            : in std_logic;
    iRESET_N        : in std_logic;
    inewValue       : in std_logic;                                 -- indicates a new input value
    iIIR_RX         : in std_logic_vector (INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0); -- singed is expected
    oDone           : out std_logic;                                -- Done Flag for next Filter
    oIIR_TX         : out std_logic_vector (OUTPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0)-- Output
    );
end entity IIR;

architecture BEH_FixCoefficientIIR of IIR is

type STATE_TYPE is (idle, mul, s1, s2, s3, s4, convert, finished);
signal state : STATE_TYPE;
constant cA1 : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0)  := to_signed(A1,INPUT_WIDTH);-- A1
constant cA2 : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0)  := to_signed(A2,INPUT_WIDTH);-- A2
constant cB0 : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0)  := to_signed(B0,INPUT_WIDTH);-- B1
constant cB1 : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0)  := to_signed(B1,INPUT_WIDTH);-- B1
constant cB2 : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0)  := to_signed(B2,INPUT_WIDTH);-- B1

signal nSUMX    : signed(INPUT_WIDTH+1 downto 0);
signal nSUMA1A2    : signed(INPUT_WIDTH+1 downto 0);
signal nSUMB1B2    : signed(INPUT_WIDTH+1 downto 0);
signal nSUMXB0    : signed(INPUT_WIDTH+1 downto 0);
signal nB0      : signed((INPUT_WIDTH*2)+1 downto 0);
signal nB1      : signed((INPUT_WIDTH*2)+1 downto 0);
signal nB2      : signed((INPUT_WIDTH*2)+1 downto 0);
signal nA1      : signed((INPUT_WIDTH*2)+1 downto 0);
signal nA2      : signed((INPUT_WIDTH*2)+1 downto 0);
signal nZ1      : signed(INPUT_WIDTH+1 downto 0);
signal nZ2      : signed(INPUT_WIDTH+1 downto 0);
signal nY       : std_logic_vector(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal nX       : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);

begin
IIR_STAGES: process (iCLK, iRESET_N)
begin

if(rising_edge(iCLK)) then
    if(iRESET_N = '0') then                 -- Reset Signals and Output
        nSUMX       <= (others => '0');
        nSUMA1A2    <= (others => '0');
        nSUMB1B2    <= (others => '0');
        nSUMXB0     <= (others => '0');
        nZ1         <= (others => '0');
        nZ2         <= (others => '0');
        nB0         <= (others => '0');
        nB1         <= (others => '0');
        nB2         <= (others => '0');
        nA1         <= (others => '0');
        nA2         <= (others => '0');
        nX          <= (others => '0');
        nY          <= (others => '0');
        oDone       <= '0';
        oIIR_TX     <= (others => '0');
        state       <= idle;
    else
        case state is 
            when idle =>
                oDone       <= '0';
                if(iNewValue = '1') then                
                    state   <= mul;
                    nX      <= signed(iIIR_RX);
                end if;
            when mul =>                     -- Multiply signals for sums
                nA1         <= nZ1 * cA1;
                nA2         <= nZ2 * cA2;
                nB1         <= nZ1 * cB1;
                nB2         <= nZ2 * cB2;
                state       <= s1;
            when s1 =>                      -- Create sums 
                nSUMA1A2    <= nA1(nA1'left downto INPUT_WIDTH) - nA2(nA2'left downto INPUT_WIDTH);
                nSUMB1B2    <= nB1(nB1'left downto INPUT_WIDTH) +  nB2(nB2'left downto INPUT_WIDTH);
                state       <= s2;
            when s2 =>                      -- Create Input sum
                nSUMX       <= nX -  nSUMA1A2;
                state       <= s3;
            when s3 =>                      -- Save new values into register and multiply with coefficient B0 for Output-Sum
                nZ1         <= nSUMX;
                nZ2         <= nZ1;
                nB0         <= nSUMX * cB0;
                state   <= s4;
            when s4 =>                      -- Add XB0 and B1B2 summation
                nSUMXB0     <= nB0(nB0'left downto INPUT_WIDTH) + nSUMB1B2;
                state       <= convert;

            when convert =>                 -- convert signed to std logic vector
                nY          <= std_logic_vector(nSUMXB0(nSUMXB0'left downto nSUMXB0'left-INPUT_WIDTH+1));
                state       <= finished;
            when finished =>                -- grab highest bits for output and set Done flag
                oIIR_TX <= nY(nY'left downto (nY'left - OUTPUT_WIDTH+1));
                oDone       <= '1';
                state <= idle;
            when others =>
                state <= idle;
        end case;
    end if;

end if;

end process IIR_STAGES;

end architecture BEH_FixCoefficientIIR;
```

[image: Matlab Filter response of IIR, CIC and both signals combined]

New Async implementation

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;    
use ieee.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;      
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;


entity IIR is
generic (
    OUTPUT_WIDTH : integer := 48;
    INPUT_WIDTH : integer := 48;
    B0 : integer := 14419;         -- = ((2^31)/1,995) * 0,000013396 
    B1 : integer := -14105;          -- = ((2^31)/1,995) * -0,000013103
    B2 : integer := 14419;         -- = ((2^31)/1,995) * 0,000013396 
    A1 : integer := -2147268361;        -- = ((2^31)/1,995) * -1,9948 
    A2 : integer := 1070803162          -- = ((2^31)/1,995) * 0,99477 
    );

port (
    iCLK            : in std_logic;
    iRESET_N        : in std_logic;
    inewValue       : in std_logic;                                 -- indicates a new input value
    iIIR_RX         : in std_logic_vector (INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0); -- singed is expected
    oDone           : out std_logic;                                -- Done Flag for next Filter
    oIIR_TX         : out std_logic_vector (OUTPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0)-- Output
    );
end entity IIR;

architecture BEH_FixCoefficientIIR of IIR is



constant cA1 : signed(31 downto 0)  := to_signed(A1,32);-- A1
constant cA2 : signed(31 downto 0)  := to_signed(A2,32);-- A2
constant cB0 : signed(31 downto 0)  := to_signed(B0,32);-- B1
constant cB1 : signed(31 downto 0)  := to_signed(B1,32);-- B1
constant cB2 : signed(31 downto 0)  := to_signed(B2,32);-- B1

signal nSUMX    : signed(48 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nSUMA1A2    : signed(48 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nSUMB1B2    : signed(48 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nSUMXB0    : signed(48 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nB0      : signed(80 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nB1      : signed(80 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nB2      : signed(80 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nA1      : signed(80 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nA2      : signed(80 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nZ1      : signed(48 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nZ2      : signed(48 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nY       : std_logic_vector(47 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal nX       : signed(47 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin
nB0 <= nSUMX * cB0;
nB1 <= nZ1 * cB1;
nB2 <= nZ2 * cB2;
nA1 <= nZ1 * cA1;
nA2 <= nZ2 * cA2;
nSUMA1A2 <= nA1(80 downto 32) + nA2(80 downto 32);
nSUMB1B2 <= nB1(80 downto 32) + nB2(80 downto 32);
nSUMXB0 <= nB0(80 downto 32) + nSUMB1B2;
nSUMX <= nX + nSUMA1A2(48 downto 0);
IIR_STAGES: process (iCLK, iRESET_N)
begin

if(rising_edge(iCLK)) then
    if(iNewValue = '1') then 
        nX <= signed(iIIR_RX);
        nZ1 <= nSUMX;
        nZ2 <= nZ1;
        oIIR_TX <= std_logic_vector(nSUMXB0(48 downto 1));
    end if;
end if;
end process IIR_STAGES;

end architecture BEH_FixCoefficientIIR;
```

Comment: Give us whole design file. We can't guess types of your signals and variables.

Comment: Put the whole VHD file into the post, hope this isn't against stackoverflow rules ^^

Comment: Why are you not initializing `state` in your reset code? On the other hand, why have a state machine at all, as opposed to a straightforward pipeline?

Comment: Publishing code is not against SE rules, but you publish it on Creative Commons license.

Comment: I want to keep asynchronous behaviour out of the implementation if I don't need to use it. Do you have an example for a pipeline implementation at hand?
That it's CC now doesn't bother me :D
Fixed the reset though

Comment: Because I'm stuck with this implementation, I tried to do it async style but guess what, again some problems but I don't know if they are on the filter side (matlab filter seems OK) or in the implementation though.

Comment: Have you tried making a test bench to simulate the design? You can then check each node at every clock cycle and make sure there are no errors.

Comment: Seems I've found a working solution, posted it for everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally written a working IIR with variable QFormat and guard bits. Seems to work pretty good, even in a cascade. Only downside is, that some coefficients that are really close to the unit circle doesn't work but every pole below 0.95 seems to be OK.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.NUMERIC_STD.ALL; 
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

entity IIR is
generic (
    OUTPUT_WIDTH : integer := 64;
    INPUT_WIDTH : integer := 64;
    QFORMAT     : integer := 11;
    GUARDBITS   : integer := 4;
    B0 : integer := 409494;  
    B1 : integer := 818988;  
    B2 : integer := 409494;  
    A1 : integer := -3954428; 
    A2 : integer := 1398100  
    );
port (
    iCLK            : in std_logic;
    iRESET_N        : in std_logic;
    inewValue       : in std_logic;                                 -- indicates a new input value
    iIIR_RX         : in std_logic_vector (INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0); -- singed is expected
    oDone           : out std_logic;                                -- Done Flag for next Filter
    oIIR_TX         : out std_logic_vector (OUTPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0)-- Output
    );
end entity IIR;

architecture behavioral of IIR is

type STATE_TYPE is (idle, mul, s1, s2, s3, s4, convert);
signal state : STATE_TYPE;
constant cA1 : signed(QFORMAT+2 downto 0)  := to_signed(A1,QFORMAT+3);-- A1
constant cA2 : signed(QFORMAT+2 downto 0)  := to_signed(A2,QFORMAT+3);-- A2
constant cB0 : signed(QFORMAT+2 downto 0)  := to_signed(B0,QFORMAT+3);-- B1
constant cB1 : signed(QFORMAT+2 downto 0)  := to_signed(B1,QFORMAT+3);-- B1
constant cB2 : signed(QFORMAT+2 downto 0)  := to_signed(B2,QFORMAT+3);-- B1

signal nSUMX    : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT+3 downto 0);             -- Sum of shifted Input and recursive sum
signal nSUMA1A2    : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT+3 downto 0);        -- Sum of recursive multiplication
signal nSUMB1B2    : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT+3 downto 0);          -- Sum of forward multiplication
signal nSUMXB0    : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT+3 downto 0);           -- Sum before Output
signal nB0      : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT+3 downto 0);           -- Multiplication of B0
signal nB1      : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT+3 downto 0);           -- Multiplication of B1
signal nB2      : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT+3 downto 0);           -- Multiplication of B2
signal nA1      : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT+3 downto 0);           -- Multiplication of A1
signal nA2      : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT+3 downto 0);           -- Multiplication of A2
signal nZ1      : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS downto 0);
signal nZ2      : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS downto 0);
signal nX       : signed(INPUT_WIDTH+QFORMAT-1 downto 0);
signal nAll0    : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT downto 0) := (others=>'0');           -- Sum before Output
signal nAll1    : signed(INPUT_WIDTH-1+GUARDBITS+QFORMAT downto 0) := (others=>'1');           -- Sum before Output
signal nMAX     : std_logic := '0';
begin
IIR_STAGES: process (iCLK, iRESET_N)
begin

if(rising_edge(iCLK)) then
    if(iRESET_N = '0') then                 -- Reset Signals and Output
        nSUMX       <= (others => '0');
        nSUMA1A2    <= (others => '0');
        nSUMB1B2    <= (others => '0');
        nSUMXB0     <= (others => '0');
        nZ1         <= (others => '0');
        nZ2         <= (others => '0');
        nB0         <= (others => '0');
        nB1         <= (others => '0');
        nB2         <= (others => '0');
        nA1         <= (others => '0');
        nA2         <= (others => '0');
        nX          <= (others => '0');
        oDone       <= '0';
        oIIR_TX     <= (others => '0');
    else
        case state is 
            when idle =>
                oDone       <= '0';
                if(iNewValue = '1') then                                                -- If new signal arrives
                    state   <= mul;                                                     -- Change state to multiply
                    nX(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0) <= signed(iIIR_RX);                      -- Get Input signal
                    if(iIIR_RX(iIIR_RX'left) = '1') then
                        nX(nX'left downto INPUT_WIDTH) <= (others => '1');
                    end if;

                end if;
            when mul =>                                                                 -- Multiply signals for sums
                nA1         <= nZ1 * cA1;                                               -- Multiplay old Data from nZ1 with cA1
                nA2         <= nZ2 * cA2;                                               -- Multiplay old Data from nZ2 with cA2
                nB1         <= nZ1 * cB1;                                               -- Multiplay old Data from nZ1 with cB1
                nB2         <= nZ2 * cB2;                                               -- Multiplay old Data from nZ2 with cB2
                nX          <= shift_left(signed(nX),QFORMAT);                          -- Right shift Input signal to meet coefficient multiplication determined by the Q-Format 2^n
                state       <= s1;
            when s1 =>                      -- Create sums 
                nSUMA1A2    <= nA1(nA1'left downto 0) + nA2(nA2'left downto 0);    
                nSUMB1B2    <= nB1(nB1'left downto 0) +  nB2(nB2'left downto 0);
                state       <= s2;
            when s2 =>                      -- Create Input sum
                nSUMX       <= nX -  nSUMA1A2(nSUMA1A2'left downto 0);                -- substract SUMA1A2 from Input signal because recursive signals always get substracted
                state       <= s3;
            when s3 =>                      -- Save new values into register and multiply with coefficient B0 for Output-Sum
                nZ1         <= nSUMX(nSUMX'left-3 downto QFORMAT);                        -- Store right value by dividing 2^Q-FORMAT
                nZ2         <= nZ1;                                                     -- Store old value
                nB0         <= nSUMX(nSUMX'left-3 downto QFORMAT) * cB0;                  -- Multiply B0 by Input signal
                state   <= s4;
            when s4 =>                      -- Add XB0 and B1B2 summation
                nSUMXB0     <= nB0(nB0'left-2 downto 0) + nSUMB1B2;                     -- Add SUMB1B2 to forward multiplication nB0 
                state       <= convert;

            when convert =>                 -- convert signed to std logic vector, check for overflow
                if((nSUMXB0(nSUMXB0'left downto nSUMXB0'left-(GUARDBITS+1)) = nAll0(nAll0'left downto nAll0'left-(GUARDBITS+1))) OR (nSUMXB0(nSUMXB0'left downto nSUMXB0'left-(GUARDBITS+1)) = nAll1(nAll1'left downto nAll1'left-(GUARDBITS+1)))) then
                    oIIR_TX     <= std_logic_vector(nSUMXB0(nSUMXB0'left-GUARDBITS-3 downto QFORMAT));
                    nMAX        <= '0';
                else
                    if(nSUMXB0(nSUMXB0'left) = '1') then
                        oIIR_TX  <= (others=>'0');
                        oIIR_TX(oIIR_TX'left) <= '1';
                        nMAX        <= '1';
                    else
                        oIIR_TX  <= (others=>'1');
                        oIIR_TX(oIIR_TX'left) <= '0';
                        nMAX        <= '1';
                    end if;
                end if;
                oDone       <= '1';
                state       <= idle;
                nX <= (others => '0');
            when others =>
                state <= idle;
        end case;
    end if;

end if;
end process IIR_STAGES;
end architecture behavioral;
```